# Iframe nao funciona em android

Tags: html, android, html5, iframe

Bom estou criando um site ai quero colocar que a musica inicia automaticamente com o site, porem nao funciona no android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo.

Infelizmente dispositivos Android não permitem um "autoplay" em iframes, acredito que o problema deve acontecer no IOS também, isto é uma limitação do sistema, para evitar perda de dados.

A solução seria você criar uma opção de play, e conforme ação do usuário, conseguiria executar, e não através do iframe.